# How to import some VueJS libraries separately, not to put all of them in only main.js file?

Tags: vue.js, plugins, import

In a VueJS application, I am currently importing font awesome libraries in main.js, however, it seems messy, so I would like to import the libraries not in main.js file, but in plugin.js, for example.

Is there any way to import libraries separately to use them globally?

I would be grateful if you could answer this. Thank you in advance.

[main.js is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp0SU.png)

Comment: You should be able to put those imports into plugin.js then import plugin.js inside of main.js. Just make sure you load plugin.js before other things that may need those libraries. Also note this still means those libraries are imported globally. So its more of an organization thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as you told me, I tried to move all of the libraries to a plugin.js file, and then just imported the file in main.js without exporting any object from the plugin.js, successfully registered it globally.